# SQL recursive calculate based on previous calculation

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, calculated-columns, sql-server-express

Say we have the following SQL Server table

```
date, qty, debit
```

I want to calculate a `NewDebit` value based on the formula shown here. I have tried everything - grouping, partition, cte - it is just not happening...

[image]

Anything I try is either a recursive CTE, or partition by, it seems I can't get the previous sum of the calculated results.

Comment: Pure SQL is agnostic to data order. Depending on your DBMS there may be a functionality implemented to solve your problem. Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: sorry i just tag it: its sql express

Comment: probably by combining lag and recursive cte you can achieve that

Comment: it seems to me is a like parent child relation but this time should work with dates, i somewhere i loose the logic

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data, only paste as text. Is it possible for the numbers to be negative?

Comment: While ``/6`` in last row? not /4?

Comment: My eyes tired looking all day how to solve it, I'm sorry i will correct tomorrow .it is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example

```
with  trng as( -- ordering for recursive sequentially process table 
  select *,row_number()over(order by dt)rn from test
)
,r as( -- anchor - first row
  select 0 as lvl,t.dt, qty,debit,rn
       ,cast(0.0 as float) tsum
       ,debit as newdebit
       ,cast('0' as varchar(100)) expr
       ,formula,testvalue
  from trng t
  where rn=1
  union all
  select r.lvl+1 lvl,t.dt, t.qty,r.debit,t.rn
    ,(r.newdebit+r.tsum) tsum    -- cumulative sum
    ,(r.newdebit+r.tsum)/t.qty newdebit -- partial sum
   -- for debug and clarity
    ,cast(concat(r.expr,'+',r.newdebit) as varchar(100)) expr
    ,t.formula,t.testvalue
  from r inner join trng t on t.rn=(r.rn+1)

)
select dt,qty,debit,newdebit,lvl,rn,tsum
  ,concat('(',expr,')/',qty) exprn
  ,formula,testvalue
from r
```

Output is

| dt | qty | debit | newdebit | lvl | rn | tsum | exprn | formula | testvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 | 5 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 1 | 0 | (0)/5 | 100 | 100 |
| 2024-02-02 | 8 | 100 | 12.5 | 1 | 2 | 100 | (0+100)/8 | 100/8 | 12.5 |
| 2024-02-03 | 3 | 100 | 37.5 | 2 | 3 | 112.5 | (0+100+12.5)/3 | (100+12.5)/3 | 37.5 |
| 2024-02-04 | 6 | 100 | 25 | 3 | 4 | 150 | (0+100+12.5+37.5)/6 | (100+12.5+37.5)/6 | 25 |
| 2024-02-05 | 4 | 100 | 43.75 | 4 | 5 | 175 | (0+100+12.5+37.5+25)/4 | (100+12.5+37.5+25)/4 | 43.75 |

with test data

```
create table test (dt date, qty int, debit float,formula varchar(100),testValue float);
insert into test values
 ('2024-02-01',5,100,'100','100')
,('2024-02-02',8,150,'100/8',12.5)
,('2024-02-03',3, 50,'(100+12.5)/3',37.5)
,('2024-02-04',6,120,'(100+12.5+37.5)/6',25)
,('2024-02-05',4, 80,'(100+12.5+37.5+25)/4',43.75)
;
```